# How to connect MySQL to Kafka cluster

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to learn kafka technology and I want to setup a small pipeline in my pc which will take data from mysql and parse them into a kafka cluster.

For a small research that I made, I saw that the best way for this is KAFKA CONNECTOR.
Can someone please help with tips or information about how to implement the above logic?

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://rmoff.net/2018/03/24/streaming-data-from-mysql-into-kafka-with-kafka-connect-and-debezium/) for an example of the MySQL->Kafka bit specifically. [Here's an example](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/build-a-streaming-pipeline) of combining data streamed data from MySQL with data produced directly to Kafka and processing both together.

Comment: You may also use [debezium](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the JDBC Source connector to pull data from your MySQL server to Kafka topic for further processing. Please find the link to the [Confluent JDBC source connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/source-connector/index.html). Please view the various configuration the connector offers to better align your data for subsequent processing.

Comment: I think because the pipeline architecture is MySql -> Kafka, I need the JDBC source connector. Am I wrong?